# How to group 2 jQuery animation's complete callbacks?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My function has different paths of execution, where one or multiple `.animate` jQuery methods might be called. These animation should start at the same time and shouldn't be serialized. For example:

```
function moveDown()
{
    busy = true;
    if(some condition)
    {
        $(".selFrame").animate({top: $("#row" + currentSelRowIndex).offset().top});
    }
    else
    {
        $(".container").animate({scrollTop: $("#row" + currentRowIndex).offset().top - $("#row0").offset().top});
        $(".selFrame").animate({top: ($(".selFrame").offset().top + ch - remaining)});
    }
}
```

My goal is not detect using some `busy` variable whether all animations have been finished, no matter through which exacution path we went. For one animation call it's easy to reset `busy` variable on animation `complete`. However, I'm not sure how to combine 2 or more animations into one event, where I can reset `busy` variable, to make sure that all animations are completed.

UPDATE

Unfortunately filtering solution didn't gave good results after thorough testing.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    var runningAnimations = $(".container, .selFrame").filter(":animated").length;
    if(runningAnimations == 0)
    {
        switch(e.keyCode)
        {
        case 40: 
            moveDown();
            break;
```

It works much better than without, but sometimes, on double animation cases allowing re-entrance.

I'm going to try second method with `promise`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to be notified when all animations related to a collection of elements have finished, you may use [`promise`](https://api.jquery.com/promise/):

```
$(".container, .selFrame").promise().then(function(){
      // all finished
      // we may change a boolean but usually we would call a callback
});
```

This can for example come just after your `if/else`.

Comment: This method proves to be much more stable, comparing with `filter`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an integer holding the number of animations and subtract one on the callback of each animation or check if its value is 1:

```
    if(some condition)
    {
        busy = 1;
        $(".selFrame").animate({top: $("#row" + currentSelRowIndex).offset().top} , function(){
             busy--;
        });
    }
    else
    {
        busy = 2;
        $(".container").animate({scrollTop: $("#row" + currentRowIndex).offset().top - $("#row0").offset().top}, function(){
             if(busy == 1) // all the animations have ended
             busy--;
        });

        $(".selFrame").animate({top: ($(".selFrame").offset().top + ch - remaining), function(){
             if(busy == 1) // all the animations have ended
             busy--;
        }});
    }
```

You can also use the `:animated` selector with `setTimeOut`:

```
setTimeOut(function(){
    var runningAnimations = $( ".container, .selFrame" ).filter( ":animated" ).length;
   }, 500);
```

Comment: Sorry, how `setTimeOut` is related to the second solution?

Comment: I have updated the answer adding the `setTimeOut` implementation

Comment: ah I see now. I could just use `runningAnimations` without timeout whenever I need to make decision if I can run my routine based on whether there are active animations or not. It seems I don't even need `setTimeOut`.

Comment: You can as long as there is something that triggers the checking since the animations run asynchronously, that was the use of `setTimeOut`